# Visual studio error at 0xC00001A5. How do I handle this?

Tags: c++

So this is my coding. It is a program for flight seating arrangement and this is just to create a random filled and vacant seating for now. I have looked for other similar problems but I was unlucky:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define ROWS 13
#define SEATS 6


void int_seats(char array[][SEATS], int elements);
void seat_map(char seats[ROWS][SEATS]);

int main(void)
{
    char section[ROWS][SEATS] = { 0 };
    unsigned int i = 0, j = 0, row = 0, seat = 0, seats_available = 0;
    string answer;
        // Initialize seats with random values of 'X' occupied or '*' available
    int_seats(section, ROWS);
        
        // Print a map of the section
    seat_map(section);
        // Determine the number of seats available
        //Sell a seat to customer

}

// Function Initialize array
// Required global value: SEATS

void int_seats(char array[][SEATS], int elements)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; 1 < elements; i++)  //goes through row
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SEATS; j++) //goes through the column in each row
        {
            if (rand() % 2 == 0)    // % gives 1 OR 0
                array[i][j] = '*';  //empty seats 
            else
                **array[i][j] = 'X';**  //occupied seat
        }
    }
    return ;
}

void seat_map(char seats[ROWS][SEATS])
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    cout << "SEAT MAP" << endl;

    cout << "SEAT   ";
    for (j = 0; j < SEATS; j++) 
    {
        if (j == 3)
            cout << "  "; //print spaces between aisle
        cout << setw(2) << j + 1;
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        cout << "ROW   ";
        cout << setw(2) << i + 1;
        for (j = 0; j < SEATS; j++)
        {
            if (j == 3)
                cout << "  ";
            cout << setw(2) << seats[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

But when I debug it I get the output

> Unhandled exception at 0x2A58582A in lab.exe: 0xC00001A5:
> An invalid exception handler routine has been detected (parameters:
> 0x00000003).

from this part of the code:

```
void int_seats(char array[][SEATS], int elements)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; 1 < elements; i++)  //goes through row
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SEATS; j++) //goes through the column in each row
        {
            if (rand() % 2 == 0)    // % gives 1 OR 0
                array[i][j] = '*';  //empty seats 
            else
                array[i][j] = 'X';  //occupied seat
        }
    }
    return ;
}
```

specifically the error indicates this line:

```
array[i][j] = 'X';  //occupied seat
```

I tried to understand it as much as I could but I really have no idea. A little help is much appreciated.

Comment: Then that basically means there's something wrong with indexing. Learn to debug, look at the contents of `array`, `i` and `j` while debugging it

Comment: `1 < elements` should probably be `i < elements`.